Exporting Lidar SLAM output to LAS from RViz and Aggregating Trajectories
I hope everyone is well. I ran SLAM using ROS on a PCAP from the Hesai OT128. The PCAP was converted to a bag file so that it can be inputted into the Kitware SLAM library. I was able to get a SLAM output using this method; however the resulting Point Cloud is restricted to only RViz. I was wondering if there is any way to export this Point Cloud to a las file. I tried the "save maps" option which you see on the right, however it seems to export nothing at all (it gives a dialog box to export something; however ends up exporting nothing). Furthermore, I was wondering there is a way to aggregate points based on the trajectory like there is in LidarView. Please let me know if someone can help me with this; thank you!
Here is how my SLAMMED output looks like:

If needed, I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic.
